# Cannot load underlying module for 'Darwin'

Tags: swift, package, darwin

When I try swift package generate-xcodeproj I get -

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'Darwin'
Can't parse Package.swift manifest file because it contains invalid format. Fix Package.swift file format and try again.
```

I'm sure that everything is fine with my Package.swift. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, restarting the terminal fixed the issue. The error message is confusing because it didn't have anything to do with Package.swift for me too.